# How to generate Normal Maps from Lighting Profiles?

Tags: normal-mapping, lightmap

How might I go about generating a normal map from a lighting profile(light map)? I saw "Sprite Lamp" however, if possible, if there is some sort of math I can do myself to convert a lighting profile to a normal map, how might I go about doing that? Or convert multiple lighting profiles to one normal map, how would I do that?

I don't have $35 to shell out currently, so I'd like to generate the normal maps myself. If you don't know what Sprite Lamp is, check out this link: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=193335844

Comment: Take the normal mapping equation, apply basic algebra...

Comment: Yup. Although, the problem is doing what sprite lamp did and combine lighting profiles into a single normal map.

Comment: If you apply the algebra, you will see that you do not have enough information to solve this from only a single angle. You need to build a system of equations from multiple instances of the normal shading formula to remove all degrees of freedom.

Comment: Here's a hint, I put this into Mathematica and it basically gave me the answer back: `Solve[{
  (nx * -lx1 + ny * -ly1 + nz*-lz1 )*color == pix1,
  (nx * -lx2 + ny * -ly2 + nz*-lz2 )*color == pix2,
  nx^2 + ny^2 + nz^2 == 1},
 {nx, ny, nz}]` It's not even close to perfect, but neither is your data, good luck!

Comment: What is wrong with my data...? I provided enough information...

Comment: I mean that the images won't have pixel perfect lighting, so your main challenge in development will be fine tuning the algorithm to deal with noise in the images